# Duplicate title error after redirecting with 301

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, gwt, seo

let you explain every point:

I have duplicate title issue with 404 error pages, I have redirect all pages with 301 redirection with use of WordPress Plugin. And it works and decrease the error, After that I have update plugin sitemap-index, and all error are back. I have checked some of the link and redirect, I have used robots.txt to block links which are having 301 redirect.

1. Does it effect, if we redirect more then one link in single page?
2. Does I need to remove 301 redirection to solve duplicate title?
3. Does I  need to use different link for redirect?

Thanks in advance

Digant

Comment: Your 404 pages probably arent set up correctly if they are being reported in webmaster tools as duplicated titles. Ensure they return a true 404 and no need to redirect them anywhere.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not programming related may fit for http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't block the 301 redirected links with `robots.txt`. Google needs to reprocess those links/pages to take your latest modifications into account.

> Does it effect, if we redirect more then one link in single page?

No, there is no issue with that.

> Does I need to remove 301 redirection to solve duplicate title?

To solve duplicate title, you need to set different titles in each page and let Google reprocess your pages. Don't block them in your `robots.txt`.

> Does I need to use different link for redirect?

This question is not clear to me. Anyway, redirects are unrelated to titles. Titles are defined in the `<head>` section of a document.

Comment: Hello Jverstry,

Thanks for the answers, I got it. I have block 301 links in robots.txt. and about 3rd question:

It means that if i have page link as of now:

www.abc.com/abc/1  and i redirect with www.abc.com/abc/
www.abc.com/abc/2 and i redirect with www.abc.com/abc/
www.abc.com/abc/3 and i redirect with www.abc.com/abc/
if i used this type of link or you can say unique links like this:

www.abc.com/abc/1 redirect with www.abc.com/abc
www.abc.com/abc/2 redirect with www.abc.com/xyz
www.abc.com/abc/3 redirect with www.abc.com/123

so is it resolve this problem? or is it make any different?

Comment: You can only have one redirect per page. You can cascade redirects if you need to (page A -> page B -> page C), but if you can avoid it and point directly to the last page (page A -> page C), it is better. But remember redirects are unrelated to title issues.